# Should I add release sign in configuration in android projects?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We have two options to build app bundles in android studio. One with build -> build bundles and other with build -> generate signed bundle. The first gives debug apk and second one gives a release apk. I want to know if I have to add sign in configuration in build.gradle file to get a signed apk. In youtube videos it is required but in android documentation it is not mentioned.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("\\xxxxx.jks")
        storePassword "xxxxx"
        keyAlias "xxxxx"
        keyPassword "xxxx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have to sign it, just not necessarily with Gradle like this. The official documentation describes it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing), but they only explain how to do it using Android Studio's wizard, and not how to do it with Gradle, which is the easier long-term way to do it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you need to do that to get a Generate SignedApk. Just go ahead with the Generate Signed Bundle method and it will do that for you. You will also see where you will be asked put in your keyAlias, keyStore and the rest. And Generating a Signed Apk has both the release and Debug options and not just the 'release' if that is what you meant.